Time delay estimation for superimposed random signals sampled from a multivariate Gaussian mixture?
Suppose my signal model is:
$$
\mathbf{y} = D(\tau_1) \mathbf{x}_1 + D(\tau_2) \mathbf{x}_2
$$
where $D(\tau)$ is a delay matrix that shifts a signal by $\tau$ samples.
$\mathbf{x}_1$ and $\mathbf{x}_2$ are not known, but we do know the parameters of the multivariate Gaussian mixture distribution they're independently drawn from: $\sum_{i=1}^M \phi_i\mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{{\mu}}_i, C_i)$.
The task is to estimate $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ given an observation $\mathbf{y}$.
How do I correctly construct the likelihood function for the delay parameters $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$?

Here's my attempt, based on the following properties of Gaussian mixture (GM) random variables (which I'm not totally sure of!):

An affine transformation of a GM random variable is a GM random variable.
If $Z_1 \sim \sum_{i=1}^M \phi_{1i} \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{{\mu}}_{1i}, C_{1i})$ and $Z_2 \sim \sum_{i=1}^M \phi_{2i} \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{{\mu}}_{2i}, C_{2i})$, then

$$
Z_1 + Z_2 \sim \sum_{i=1}^M \sum_{j=1}^M \phi_{1i} \phi_{2j} \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{{\mu}}_{1i} + \boldsymbol{{\mu}}_{2j}, C_{1i} + C_{2j})
$$
It follows that the conditional distribution of $\mathbf{y}$ given $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^M \sum_{j=1}^M \phi_i \phi_j \mathcal{N}\left[D(\tau_1) \boldsymbol{{\mu}}_i + D(\tau_2) \boldsymbol{{\mu}}_j, D(\tau_1) C_i D(\tau_1)^T + D(\tau_2) C_j D(\tau_2)^T\right]
$$
And therefore, the likelihood of $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ is, upto a constant:
$$
\begin{aligned}
L(\tau_1, \tau_2) &= p(\mathbf{y} \mid \tau_1, \tau_2) \\
&= \sum_{i,j} \phi_i \phi_j \exp \left[ -\frac{1}{2} ||\mathbf{y} - \bar{\mathbf{y}}_{ij}||^2_{B_{ij}} \right]
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\bar{\mathbf{y}}_{ij} = D(\tau_1) \boldsymbol{{\mu}}_i + D(\tau_2) \boldsymbol{{\mu}}_j$ and $B_{ij} = D(\tau_1) C_i D(\tau_1)^T + D(\tau_2) C_j D(\tau_2)^T$.

I'm quite unsure about my answer because

I cannot find a single instance in the literature that models entire signals as multivariate GMMs in the specific way that I do.
The shift matrix $D(\tau)$ is singular- will my derivation still hold?

